# javascript better way to create object with a method using function

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

I'm new to javascript and am trying to create an object that I can then fill a list with instances of. This code I have works, but it feels redundant to have the "this." keyword on every line. Is there a neater/more appropriate way to create an object like this?

Here is my current object:

```
    var Particle = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.xspeed = 0;
    this.yspeed = 0;
    this.xacc = 0;
    this.yacc = 0;

    this.update = function() {
        this.x += this.xspeed;
        this.y += this.yspeed;
        this.xspeed += this.xacc;
        this.yspeed += this.yacc;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your assistance in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `this` is mandatory in Javascript, even if the other languages deduce it.

Today [Ecmascript classes are supported by any browser excepting IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). It could be a good way to use class syntax if you want to use object oriented programming.

```js
class Particle {
    constructor(x, y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.xspeed = 0;
      this.yspeed = 0;
      this.xacc = 0;
      this.yacc = 0;
    }

    update() {
        this.x += this.xspeed;
        this.y += this.yspeed;
        this.xspeed += this.xacc;
        this.yspeed += this.yacc;
    }
}

const particle = new Particle(1, 2);
particle.update();
console.log(particle);
```

Comment: While I'm a bit sad that `this.` is mandatory, I didn't realise that classes were available for use like this, its pretty much exactly what I was trying to emulate. So thanks for the response Benjamin!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Object.assign` and an object literal:

```
var Particle = function(x, y) {
 Object.assign(this, {
   x, y,
   xspeed: 0,
   yspeed: 0,
   xacc: 0,
   yacc:0,
 });
 //...
};
```

As you aren't using inheritance, you could also just return a new object:

```
const Particle = (x, y) => ({
   x, y,
   xspeed: 0,
   yspeed: 0,
   xacc: 0,
   yacc:0,
   update() {
    this.x += this.xspeed;
    this.y += this.yspeed;
    this.xspeed += this.xacc;
    this.yspeed += this.yacc;
  },
});
```

Comment: This does seem cleaner, but another comment from Tino said my current method makes sense given I want to use multiple instances with their own values. Does this mean there are differences in how the variables are assigned to the object for each of these methods? Thanks

Comment: @adam no there aren't, not sure what he is talking about.

Comment: ok cool thanks, is there a way to create this kind of object with a constructor without using the function() declaration? because using the standard assignment of object = {} seems much cleaner but it doesn't seem to support constructors.

Comment: that's great I much prefer that over the function method, thanks so much for your help Jonas.

Answer (score 0):

About the high usage of `this` you could use `Object.assign` to fix the high use of value assignment in the base code. (`this.value = value`)

since you want multiple instances with their own values it is logical to use the `this` scope for the values you want to use. (using the values defined in the `this` scope)

Comment: thanks for the response, I left a comment on Jonas' answer asking about the differences between my method and the object.assign method, are there any?

Comment: The `Object.assign` function will bind values to the this scope, there is no difference in outcome, the `Object.assign` is cleaner and you should go for that. I meant to say that you using the `this` scope in this context is not a bad thing. @Jonas 's answer is great.

Just read my answer again, it's nor really clear, i'll edit it